# Why can stability Factor be defined like this ? What does "stability" mean here? let voltage be stable? or let some of current be stable?

Tags: amplifier, bjt, stability

i saw some information about stability from here : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jw_GUiswndw&t=422s ,but i have some problems,why can stability Factor ,\$S\$, be defined like this ?

\$S=\frac{\Delta I_C}{\Delta I_{CO}}\$,

\$\Delta I_C\$ is the collector current changes,

\$\Delta I_{CO}\$ is the reverse saturation current changes

I mean,why is \$\frac{\Delta I_C}{\Delta I_{CO}}\$ has relation with "stability" ?why won't someone define \$S=\frac{\Delta I_{CO}}{\Delta I_C}\$, or \$ S= { V_{out} - V_{in} }\$ ,what does the stability mean in here?

Comment: You should disclose your sources for this discussion. My crystal ball is broken. But if I had to guess, this issue is about ***temperature***. Something you didn't even bring up here. It's also likely to be discussing the CE configuration, where \$I_\text{CEO}=\frac1{1-\alpha} I_\text{CBO}\$. The temperature-dependence of \$I_\text{CBO}\$ is already strong, so it really plays into ***temperature***-instability in CE configured circuits. Anyway, please disclose the context. If it is not about temperature, you need to say so. If so, I'll back away because it figures much more in CE-stability.

Comment: @jonk i have edited the question,thx for your suggestion

Comment: Notice that [50 seconds into the video](https://youtu.be/jw_GUiswndw?t=47) --- hmm -- ***TEMPERATURE*** is splatted all over the place?

Comment: Consider \$\frac{\frac{\text{d}\, I_\text{C}}{\text{d}\,Parameter}}{\frac{\text{d}\, I_\text{CEO}}{\text{d}\,Parameter}}=\frac{\text{d}\, I_\text{C}}{\text{d}\, I_\text{CEO}},\text{ due to some <External Parameter>.}\$. I think the external parameter under discussion is laid out right at the start of the video -- **temperature**. So, \$\frac{\frac{\text{d}\, I_\text{C}}{\text{d}\,T}}{\frac{\text{d}\, I_\text{CEO}}{\text{d}\,T}}=\frac{\text{d}\, I_\text{C}}{\text{d}\, I_\text{CEO}}\$. It may be confusing because the \$\text{d}\,T\$ cancels out. But it is implicitly there. Does this clarify?

Comment: @jonk well no,then why is \$(dI_C/dT)/(d I_{CEO}/dT)\$,not \$((d I_{CEO}/dT)/(dI_C/dT)\$,what are \$(dI_C/dT)\$ and  \$(d I_{CEO}/dT)\$

Comment: because we can easily search the formula of stability Factor,and it always show us this formula: \$\frac{\Delta I_C}{\Delta I_{CO}}\$,but never say why should we  define the formula like that ?there should be some reason why,and according to that reason,we define the  \$S=\frac{\Delta I_C}{\Delta I_{CO}}\$

Comment: The video starts out talking about external parameters. It then immediately discusses temperature. I'm not sure I can explain things better, right now. Maybe something will come to mind, later on.